# Firewall/NAT for LWM2M

Tags: lwm2m

Has anyone got this Firewall recipe to work

> "For a firewall to support  LwM2M , it should be configured to allow
>   outgoing UDP packets to destination port 5683 (other  ports can be
>   configured), and a llow incoming UDP packets back to the source
>   address/port of the outgoing UDP packet for a  period of at least 240
>   seconds."

from section 8.2.1. at this URL

http://openmobilealliance.org/release/LightweightM2M/V1_0_2-20180209-A/OMA-TS-LightweightM2M-V1_0_2-20180209-A.pdf

The first part is easy, but the incoming packets?

We are looking for IPTABLES recipes, but any positive experience with ANY firewall will be helpful.

Comment: In general a stateful firewall will automatically allow RELATED traffic and after an outgoing connection is established the return packets will be allowed into your network and a bi-directional connection is established.

Comment: This is over UDP. There is no connection.

Comment: Yes. UDP is connectionless, and I should probably have used hyphens around the word "connection" but that does not negate the fact that in iptables accepting RELATED traffic will also work for UDP.  (For instance for the most widely used UDP protocol, DNS resolution, you typically don't explicitly open up incoming port 53 to receive answers to the DNS queries you send out).

Comment: Investigating https://serverfault.com/questions/123208/iptables-p-udp-state-established